# Why is the width of `~` different than `➜` on iTerm2 when using zsh with spaceship-prompt?

Tags: iterm, zsh

[image: iTerm2]

Using iTerm2. Installed `zsh`, [spaceship-prompt](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt) and [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode).

Why is the width of `~` different than `➜`?

Comment: How did you enter the arrow symbol? What Unicode point is it?

Comment: Because you are using a THEME to customise it. This is defined on the shell variable `$PS1` . try `echo $PS1` and you will see where it is defined. Change it by editing `~/.zshrc`. About the width, is because the font used is not a monospaced font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found what’s going on... `SPACESHIP_CHAR_SYMBOL` is set to `➜` (Heavy Round-Tipped Rightwards Arrow, unicode `U+279C`) by default vs `→` (Rightwards Arrow, unicode `U+2192`) which has the right width. PR in the making.

Submitted a [PR](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt/pull/722) to [spaceship-prompt](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt).

Answer (score 4):

Prompt is defined on the shell variable $PS1

try `echo $PS1` and you will see its definition. Change it by editing `~/.zshrc` if you want.

**About the width**, it is because the font used on your terminal **is not a monospaced font**. Choose any monospaced, or fixed-size font, if you want all character to be the same width.